# Joomla editors TinyMCE and JCE eliminating attributes

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla3.0, joomla-content-editor

I have the following HTML markup

```
<video poster="home-bg.jpg" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" data-autoplay="" playsinline="" width="982" height="552">
<source src="short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The problem is that the Joomla editors, at least the two main ones tinyMCE and JCE, are eliminating the attribute playsinline from the Video tag.

I already tried adding exceptions or adding this attribute to valid attributes but I have had not success.

The attribute gets eliminated no matter what.

If I disable all editors the attribute remains but I need the editors active.

Any help?

Comment: Where did you add exceptions / this attribute -- in /plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php ?

Comment: Please post Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify how an element is filtered by TinyMCE using the `extended_valid_elements` in `init` method, you can specify the html attributes you want to keep:

```
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea', 
    extended_valid_elements : 'video[autoplay|muted|loop|playsinline|class]'
});
```